# Create and Open Database xCode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile

So I'm new to XCode and I want to store my data in a database using Sqlite3. I have a class users where I have this method.

```
-(void)createOrOpenDB
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.db"];
    char *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &userDB)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, CONFIRM TEXT, EMAIL TEXT)";
            sqlite3_exec(userDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
            sqlite3_close(userDB);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have also another class where I would like to create another table. But it won't work because this methods says that the database already exists.

How can I just open that database in another class to create a new table?

Comment: Have you thought about using CoreData? I have used SQL databases and I can say working with CoreData keeps your code much cleaner and you can see a visual of your DB entities. Heres a good tutorial if your interested: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thanks :) I will check if this can help me :)

Comment: What's the problem if the DB already exists? Simply use it. You should create a single instance that handles DB access for all your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you stay with sqlite, you are better off having a single method that opens or creates the database. If the database is created, the entire schema gets created all at once. Now all of your classes can call the single method.

This will be makes things much easier now and later. Sometime down the road your scheme may change. This one method can also be written to update the schema as needed.